# Is there any way to install typescript npm packages in their native typescript instead of javascript for the purpose of reading source code?

Tags: typescript, npm

My terminology may be incorrect and I admit I don't know the entire process of how a library, written in typecript, compiles itself to javascript before it's installed in the `node_modules` folder but:

Coming from a PHP background I'm used to being able to dig into any library I download via composer in my `vendors` folder and see *the actual* php code the library was written in.

In my current Angular 2 project when I download a typescript library I get, I don't know the correct term, but it's basically an abstract class or some kind of contract (I guess a class declaration?):

```
export declare class FormGroup extends AbstractControl {
    controls: {
        [key: string]: AbstractControl;
    };
    constructor(controls: {
        [key: string]: AbstractControl;
    }, validator?: ValidatorFn, asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn);
    /**
     * Registers a control with the group's list of controls.
     *
     * This method does not update value or validity of the control, so for
     * most cases you'll want to use {@link FormGroup.addControl} instead.
     */
    registerControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl): AbstractControl;
    /**
     * Add a control to this group.
```

Then the class compiled in js:

```
export var FormGroup = (function (_super) {
    __extends(FormGroup, _super);
    /**
     * @param {?} controls
     * @param {?=} validator
     * @param {?=} asyncValidator
     */
    function FormGroup(controls, validator, asyncValidator) {
        if (validator === void 0) { validator = null; }
        if (asyncValidator === void 0) { asyncValidator = null; }
        _super.call(this, validator, asyncValidator);
        this.controls = controls;
        this._initObservables();
        this._setUpControls();
        this.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
```

Then a mapping:

```
{"version":3,"file":"model.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../../../modules/@angular/forms/src/model.ts"],
```

Is it possible to pass a parameter to npm so this library would just download in typescript, I'll let webpack compile it to js (purely for development purposes of course) so I can browse *the actual* source when I'm developing?

Right now everytime I want to read the source I must browse github. Is this how to do it?

Comment: You can install `@types/whatever` from DefinitelyTyped that should help with syntax highlighting, it exposes the `.d.ts` module definitions. There's no reason to download the source code to take up space if you can't consume it, thus the reason package maintainers usually ignore the source and just expose the distribution code with `.npmignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If a module is published to npm with no source available, then that's it. You'll have to look at the modules source on github (or wherever it is).

You can install via github (`npm install username/repo-name`) to get their repo in your node_modules, though, but that might not contain the compiled JS.